# How to plot ellipse

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can plot ellipse like this:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mean = [ 19.92977907 ,  5.07380955]
width = 30
height = 1.01828848
angle = -54
ell = mpl.patches.Ellipse(xy=mean, width=width, height=height, angle = 180+angle)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(ell)

ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(-100, 100)
ax.set_ylim(-100, 100)
plt.show()
```

However, this requires me to set the axis data limits manually. Can it be set automatically? I mean, how to get rid of `ax.set_xlim(-100, 100)` and `ax.set_ylim(-100, 100)`?
Or, what is a good way of plotting ellipse?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You have some working code...

Comment: @tom, I don't want to set `xlimt` manually, how can I do it?

Comment: OK, I see. That's clearer. See my answer - you need to use `add_patch` to correctly get the data limits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `patch` using `add_patch`, not `add_artist`, then the data limits will be updated properly using `ax.autoscale`:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mean = [ 19.92977907 ,  5.07380955]
width = 30
height = 1.01828848
angle = -54
ell = mpl.patches.Ellipse(xy=mean, width=width, height=height, angle = 180+angle)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.add_patch(ell)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image]